# NewGlobalRef of a weak reference still prevent a object from garbage collected

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

To implement a callback function from the native code to Java code, I have to create a global reference using `NewGloabRef` . From the memory profile , I found that ,once I called `env->NewGlobalRef(weak_this)`, even it was a weak reference of the player object, the Player object will be available as Root Objects, which I think will prevent it from being garbage collected.

But my understanding is the weak reference won't prevent the object from garbage collected.

```
//java code

Player{

native_init(new WeakReference(this)),

}

//JNi code

//listener 
Listener::Listener(jobject weak_this)
{

//will use mObject for callback 
mObject = env->NewGlobalRef(weak_this);

}


xxxx_Player_native_init(xxxx. Object weak_this)
{

Listener l = new Listener(weak_this);

}
```

EDIT:

memory profile :

```
 Root Object 0x2C820E10 <com/trident/tv/media/player/JniTPlayer>
  com/trident/tv/media/player/JniTPlayer.trace : 0x2C83CC54 <java/lang/String>
  com/trident/tv/media/player/JniTPlayer.listenerList : 0x2C820E64 <java/util/Vector>
```

log of JNI

```
[JNI] NewGlobalRef(0x2C820E10 [com/trident/tv/media/player/JniTPlayer]) : 0x2C820E10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WeakReference` is a Java object with an ordinary reference to it.  It *contains* a reference to another object.  It is the contained reference that is "weak", not the reference to the `WeakReference` itself.

So when you call `env->NewGlobalRef(weak_this)` (assuming `weak_this` is a `WeakReference`), the effect is the same as assigning `weak_this` to a static.  It doesn't cause the object reference *contained by* the `WeakReference` to be strongly reachable.

I think you may be misinterpreting what the memory profiler is telling you.  In particular, I would expect it to show the contained reference of a `WeakReference` to be reachable ... up until the GC decided to break the link.  Try an experiment with an `WeakReference` in an ordinary `static` variable.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm starting to think that this is normal behaviour for JNI `NewGlobalRef`.  The JNI documentation is (as always) very vague about the method's behaviour.

Note that there is also a JNI method called `NewGlobalWeakRef`; see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html#27531.  If nothing else, `NewGlobalWeakRef` provides an alternative way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Stephen, I added the memory profile and JNI log here. `JniTPlayer` appeared in the Root objects section once i called `NewGlobalRef`. And, I have forced an GC before dump out the memory profile.