# Would the garbage collector destroy my object in this case?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I have a method in my `Java` code that returns an object of class A, this object is passed to a native function via `JNI` call and not used anymore in the `Java` code. But it will be used for a long term in the `C++` side.

Should I care about the garbage collector destroying my object because it does not appear anymore in the `Java` side ?

Comment: Can you show us some relevant code?

Comment: Why do you care what the garbage collector does if you're not worrying about your Object in your code? It's not like you're using the class anyway.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi - But the JNI code is still using it.

Comment: Not an expert but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185431/newglobalref-of-a-weak-reference-still-prevent-a-object-from-garbage-collected?rq=1) suggest that the global ref of the object will keep it in heap.

Comment: @Jonathan : I didn't write code yet, that's why I am wondering. Basically the A object is an image, and the native function does some heavy processing on the image (but it returns before doing the whole processing, so the object needs to be kept in memory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in detail in the [JNI Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp16785):

> The JNI divides object references used by the native code into two categories: local and global references. Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until they are explicitly freed.

So the answer to your question depends on wether you have a local reference in your C++ code or a global reference.

> Objects are passed to native methods as local references. All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references. The JNI allows the programmer to create global references from local references.

This basically means that unless you turn any of the references you get into global references explicitly (using `NewGlobalRef`), they will only be "referenced" as long as the JNI call takes. So if the code returns and no Java code references the object then it can be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not sure if I understood everything, but since I want my object to be kept in memory even after the JNI call returns, and since that after the JNI call the object is not used anymore in the Java code, I need to use global references ?

Comment: @hahaha1256: Exactly. If you don't create a global reference, then the reference will become invalid once your JNI call returns and the object might be GCed..